# How can I use SparkSession to select a subset of a postgre table but not to load full table?

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, dataframe

When I use SparkSession to get data from postgre table, I must first load the table into a DataFrame and then query some data by DataFrame API:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.xx.xx:5432/sparktest")
  .option("dbtable", "public.ml")
  .option("user", "dxy")
  .option("password", "123456")
  .load()

println(jdbcDF.count())

val sqlDF = jdbcDF.select("f1", "f2")
sqlDF.show()
```

The statement "println(jdbcDF.count())" returns the total count of table ml, but if table ml is large, is DataFrame jdbcDF also large?

I just want to query and get some specific data from table ml, that is to say, I want to load part of data in table ml into DataFrame jdbcDF so that I can save the memory.

Can anybody help me and give me an example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use like `limit(<number of rows>)`

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.xx.xx:5432/sparktest")
  .option("dbtable", "public.ml")
  .option("user", "dxy")
  .option("password", "123456")
  .limit(10)
```

Comment: But, it seems that I query the specific data in local dataframe but not in postgre, right? Can you conduct a condition query in postgre by SparkSeesion?

Comment: I am not too sure about the internals. If remember seeing significant speed ups after using limit. I guess it does not read the whole database.